# Spring:Feching parameter for post request

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Post request is as follow

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="loginpage.png"
Content-Type: image/png
```

I have following code at serverside

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/file-upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String fileUpload(Locale locale, Model model,HttpServletRequest request,@RequestParam("file")  MultipartFile[] files) 
{
}
```

I am getting file from post request as follows

```
@RequestParam("file")  MultipartFile[] files
```

but when i write

```
@RequestParam("filename") String name
```

it gives me `400 Bad request`- The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

Why so??

How to get filename??

Comment: does @RequestParam("name") work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract the file name from the MultipartFile with getOriginalFilename() method.

See the docs here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html